# 'tuple' object is not callable error using matplotlib library?

Tags: python-3.x

```
1  def auto_correlate(x):
2     cor = np.correlate(x,x,mode="full")
3     return cor[N-1:]

4  c = np.zeros(N)
5  c = auto_correlate(x-ave)/N
6  plt.plot(c)
7  plt.xlim(-1000, 10000)
8  plt.xlabel(r'$i$',fontsize=16)
9  plt.ylabel(r'$\varphi(i)$',fontsize=16)
10 print('\sigma^2 = ', std**2)
11 plt.show()
```

Why do I keep getting error 'tuple' object not callable online 7 ? please explain

Answer (score 19):

It looks like you may have overwritten the plt.xlim function.

Did you perhaps run `plt.xlim=(-1000, 10000)`? (note the "=")

type `plt.xlim` and run it to check.

Output should be something like:

```
<function matplotlib.pyplot.xlim(*args, **kwargs)>
```

Comment: thank you! one simple stupid mistake and I lost 3 hours.

Comment: So when it happens a problem like this, by using `plt.xlim()` without any arguments, you can easily reset the axis limits to their default values, without the need to restart the kernel as suggested in many other places!

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code which I tried.
plt.figure(    figsize=(14, 14))

Restart the kernel and error will go.
Even if you load the dataframe you will get the same error.

## In case anyone gets following error:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 plt.figure(    figsize=(2, 5))

## TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Answer (score -1):

This was a strange error that took my time for an hour.
Finally, I found out that in the previous cell I used `plt.xlim` with `'='` sign, in the wrong cell I hadn't got an error but it shows itself in the next cell.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32655137)